# is it possible to put a text beside the sum of a column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-foundation, power-automate

Is it possible to put a text grand Total to this

[image: Grand Total]

Comment: Are you using modern experience or classic experience?

Comment: it's still on default experience

Comment: I don't think you will be able to add any text there. Check if JSON formatting helps you: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-group-formatting

Comment: Thanks will do.